# How to fix MacBook, not reconnecting to wireless network on wakeup?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

MacBook Air 11" - Mid 2011

My MacBook is not reconnecting to the wireless network on wakeup.

Is there a setting or something that I'm missing?

Comment: Not going to add it as an answer as I haven't experienced it myself, but Dan Benjamin on The Talk Show podcast said that he had the same thing, it drove him mad, until he removed Bluetooth from the Network Preferences panel. Apparently if you need Bluetooth, you can also make sure it's listed below wifi in the order of network adapters, and that works as well.

Comment: I tried this but, i am also asked for the wireless password on every attempt. It does not even "remember" it. It's sooo sad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

**Solution**:

The network i was trying to connect to, was set not to distribute it's ID, so i typed it in or saved it somehow at some point. The fatal error is, the SECURITY TYPE *does not match* with the wireless router so every time, the computer ask again for the correct type/key combination resulting in, a disconnection from the wireless network :)

To fix it, go to **Preferences > Network > Advanced** and press the plus sign and **ADD THE ENTRY MANUAL!!!!!!!** and you will be fine.

Hope it helps, thank you all!

Comment: Just recommended this fix to a friend who saw the same thing on a brand-new Mac mini - removing BT from Network services worked for him as well.

Comment: God sent you :D I had forgotten how to fix this (chaged the SSID:D) now i need to do it again. Thank you!

Comment: Manually typing in my network credentials and replacing the current network when prompted, did the trick in my case. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Every time MacBook Air (2010) waked-up from sleep it would ask to choose network to re-connect and then took about 20 sec to actually connect. same if I turn wifi off and then on again.

solution that worked for me was: **system preferences -> network -> SET SERVICE ORDER.."** (in sub-menu next to "+"/"-" (create/remove service) at the bottom of  services list on the left).

**DRAG WIFI TO THE TOP** in Service order list -> "OK" -> "APPLY"

After that I am back to no "choose network to connect" pup-up's and wifi connects in 3 seconds. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest version of Lion?

If so there is a "[known](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3191630?start=0&tstart=0)" issue with this - my older Macbook will wake from sleep and connect to the wifi.  A few seconds later the connection will be dropped until I reselct the network.

I've tried various resets and plist deletions with no joy, and know several other people with the same issues.

I'm hoping for a fix when the next update comes around.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know this :) Let me check that. Yes Lion with latest version :)

Answer (score -1):

I've been having a problem where WiFi will not reconnect on wake from sleep - in my case the Time Machine icon is spinning as if it were running a backup. If you cancel Time Machine's backup job, WiFi will instantly re-establish itself when Time Machine finally stops processing.

It seems to be some sort of bug related to putting the Mac to sleep while Time Machine is attempting to do... something... to the Time Capsule hard drive.